# Headers are removed from middleware in production Next js

Tags: next.js, middleware, canonical-link

I have such a strange thing. Project on next js 12.3. I use middleware to add canonical link to headers. Everything works locally, and the required headers are added, but when deployed in production, the header I need is not added.

if the subdomain is not www, the canonical must be a link to the www version

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const { protocol, href } = req.nextUrl;
  const subdomain = href.replace('https://','').split('.')[0];
  if (subdomain !== 'www') {
    const urlArr = href?.split('//');
    const afterSubdomainUrl = urlArr?.slice(1, urlArr.length)?.join('//');
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    response.headers.append(
      'Link',
      `<${protocol}//www.${afterSubdomainUrl}>; rel="canonical"`,
    );
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the conditional and just add any header, is it also missing? might be your web server preventing or blocking certain headers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at DockerFile - need to implement next code at
app/Dockerfile

```
COPY middleware.ts /app/middleware.ts
RUN true
```